# Rendering React component from Redux state property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So, I'm having this specific error :

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, component, accessible, is_showed, is_rendered}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Base`.

I have a Redux state that looks like the following :

```
export const initialState = {
    links: [{
        name: 'search_files',
        component: <SearchFile/>,
        accessible: true,
        is_showed: true,
        is_rendered: false
    },
        {
            name: 'invisible_link',
            component: <SearchFile/>,
            accessible: false,
            is_showed: true,
            is_rendered: false
        }
    ],
    user: {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        is_logged: false,
        has_rights: false,
        errors: {
            summary: '',
            username: '',
            password: ''
        }
    },
    panel: {toggled: false}
};
```

My intent is to render the component pointed by the `component` property of each link. For the moment, the component is the same for the two links, it's "normal".

The `Base` component looks like this :

```
class Base extends React.Component {

    render() {
        let toRender = null;

        if (!this.props.state.user.is_logged)
            toRender = <LoginFormRender/>;
        else
        {
            toRender = this.props.state.links.find(link => {
                if (link.is_rendered) {
                    console.log(link.component);
                    return (link.component);
                }
            })
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <TopBarApp/>
                <LeftPanel/>
                {toRender}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Base;
```

The `LoginFormRender` is rendering just good, but the error is here :

```
else
        {
            toRender = this.props.state.links.find(link => {
                if (link.is_rendered) {
                    console.log(link.component);
                    return (link.component);  <==== HERE
                }
            })
        }
```

I understand that I visibly can't do it like this (but still, it works storing a component in a var, as `LoginFormRender` works) but I can't figure out how to achieve this ... Does somebody knows ? I couldn't find any question on SO that answers my question..

Thanks in advance

Comment: In general case your InitialState should not contain instances of React compontents. Maybe perform some switch by Component/Container name, but InitialState should be serializable.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. Thanks for your comment, I'll refactor this !
So if I understand well what you are saying, I can't perform what I want except by doing a switch-case ?

Comment: You can, but why not keep the raw link entities in state. 

something like this: 
toRender = this.props.state.links.find(link => {
                if (link.is_rendered) {
                
                    return (<Link {..link} />);
                }
            })

You could also improve the business logic by only putting the links to the state, that should be rendered.

Comment: @larrydahooster I didn't understand what you're trying to do with <Link/>, but the second advice is really interesting, I'll do it if I have the time ! Thanks for taking the time to comment !

Comment: @GaetanBoyals forget about my comment. The answer of Mayank Shukla fixes your probelm.

Comment: Are you getting the initial state in your app scenario from redux store? Then you should not put the Component itself on the store... You should generate it in runtime, that is what I meant. I just used <Link /> in the comment, it should have been <SearchFile />

Comment: Yes I do, initialState is my second parameter in the "createStore(my_combined_reducers, initialState)" call. Thanks again for your comments, I'm pretty new at Javascript (not to mention React and Redux) so any advice is good for the taking ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is, you are using [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and it will always return either the value in the array if an element passes the test, otherwise undefined. It will not return the item that you are returning from body.

As per [MDN DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array
>   that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is
>   returned.

Check this snippet:

```js
let a = [{a:1}, {a:2}];

let p = a.find(el => {if(el.a > 1) return 10;});

console.log('p = ', p);
```

Even though i am returning 10, but the value that p will have is `{a: 2}`.

**Solution of your problem:**

In your case `toRender` will have this value after loop:

```
{
      name: 'invisible_link',
      component: <SearchFile/>,
      accessible: false,
      is_showed: true,
      is_rendered: false
}
```

That's why it is throwing the error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name,
>   component, accessible, is_showed, is_rendered}).

So instead of rendering `{toRender}` render this:

```
{toRender.component}
```

Or write the loop like this:

```
else{
    this.props.state.links.find(link => {
        if (link.is_rendered) {
            toRender = link.component;
            return 1;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Wow, you nailed it ! Thanks for your answer, it solved the problem ! Still have to take in account the other answers :)

Comment: glad, it solved your issue :), yes instead of storing the rendered component, store the string and use conditions to render the component on the basis of string.

Answer (score 1):

State is used to have information about current application data structure, but it shouldn't have components in it. You should render components in `render()` function.

Your `render()` could look like this

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <TopBarApp/>
            <LeftPanel/>

            {this.props.state.user.is_logged ? (
                // Render menu links here
                <SearchFile/>
            ) : (
                <LoginFormRender/>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: As said in the comment of my question, I didn't know that before Vladislav Ihost told me. Still upvoting this for giving me general knowledge. Thanks !